# How come I pass thru more vertices than I can generate in GLSL Geometry Shaders?

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

How come I can pass my geometry shader N (where N is a very high number, like 10000) vertices and render them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gl_VerticesIn; ++i) {
    gl_Position = projectionmodelview_matrix_ * gl_PositionIn[i];
    EmitVertex();
}
```

...but I cant generate N vertices like this (when just passing a single vertex):

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    float f = float(i);
    gl_Position = projectionmodelview_matrix_ * vec4(f, f, f, 1.0);
    EmitVertex();
}
```

How can OpenGL even differentiate between the two?

*Note:
Ive modifier the code to access gl_PositionIn[0] etc, still the second one gives me an error.*

Comment: What `#version` are you targeting?

Comment: I am using #version 150

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all based on a fundamental misunderstanding of what the GS is doing.

You do not "pass my geometry shader N vertices". `gl_VerticesIn` is not the number of vertices in a *draw call*. A [Geometry Shader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) does not process every vertex in the draw call all at once. Geometry Shaders operate on [*primitives*](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive). And a draw call produces one or more primitives. `gl_VerticesIn` is the number of vertices in a primitive. And that is fixed for the [particular primitive type that the GS operates on](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Primitive_in.2Fout_specification).

If you draw 30 vertices with GL_TRIANGLES as your primitive type, you produce 10 triangle primitives. So your GS will be called 10 times. If you draw 30 vertices with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP as your primitive type, you will produce 28 triangle primitives. So your GS will be called 28 times.

A GS takes one primitive as input, and emits 0 or more primitives as output (that's why it ought to be called a "Primitive Shader", just like Vertex Shaders take and emit vertices and Fragment Shaders take and emit fragments). But the outputs are subject to [various output size limitations](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Output_limitations). That's why your second GS chokes; you violate the output size restrictions.

Comment: "gl_VerticesIn is not the number of vertices in a draw call." Ah, how stupid of me, when I am using GL_POINTS, gl_VerticesIn only consists of one vertex.